# Ruby on rails: JQuery autocomplete on heroku server (SQL, PostgreSql error probably)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a textfield in my rails app for which I have applied the jquery autocomplete function which works fine in my localhost.

I have uploaded the application to heroku and now it gives me an error.

After my debugging I figured out that the error is my query. In my local I'm using sql but on heroku it is PostgreSQL.

My Controller action for autocomplete:

```
@places = Place.order(:name).where("name like ? or pincode like ?" , "%#{params[:term]}%", "%#{params[:term]}%")
render json: @places.map{|p| "#{p.name} : #{p.pincode}"}
```

On heroku it was showing me an error like this

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ integer
```

So I thought it had something to do with the params for pincode (which is an integer) but I'm passing it as a string. (I'm not sure though)

So I changed the query to

```
@places = Place.order(:name).where("name like ?" , "%#{params[:term]}%")
```

Now it works fine, but doesnt search for a match in pincode.

I tried framing the query in many ways so that I can search on both but no use. Can someone help me with the query?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you must have a different version of Postgres on your local machine.

But with either version, you should be able to convert it to a text with

```
@places = Place.order(:name).where("name like ? or pincode::text like ?" , "%#{params[:term]}%", "%#{params[:term]}%")
```